# Asymptote's rendering in interactive viewing mode

Tags: 3d, asymptote, acrobat

The following example illustrates that something is wrong with Asymptote's rendering of transparency in 3D (in interactive viewing mode Acrobat Reader):[image]
The example consists mainly of two intersecting (~blue) solids of revolution (spheres), which is partially transparent (rgb(0.3,0.7,1)+opacity(0.3)). The surfaces have weird-looking "streaks" and patches on them which I think are artifacts of the rendering.

The complete .tex file for generating the picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import solids;
currentprojection = perspective(0,100,25);
currentlight=Viewport;
viewportmargin=(0.1cm,0.1cm);
unitsize(1.2cm);
triple pO=(0,0,0);
real a=0.5;
real a1=0.1;
revolution s=sphere(pO,a);
revolution s1=sphere(pO,a1);
draw(surface(s),rgb(0.3,0.7,1)+opacity(0.3));
draw(surface(s1),red+opacity(0.3));

transform3 t1=shift(0.7*X);
draw(t1*surface(s),rgb(0.3,0.7,1)+opacity(0.3));
draw(t1*surface(s1),red+opacity(0.3));

path3 gene = (0,0,0)--(0.7,0,0);
draw(gene,black+bp);

\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Can you please offer some help on this topic?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what version of Asymptote do you use. If you use the latest version, which is 2.79, you will notice that it has html output. The html format output supports webGL, and I have just try your code, and there is no transparent issue. Also, please note that the 3D support in Asymptote for the PDF file(PRC output format) is now deprecated and may have many bugs. So, please use the html with webGL as output.

Comment: @ollydbg23, hi, I'm new to LaTeX and writing code on the Overleaf.  I think, I understand, what you mean. How can I include the interactive html to my latex pdf file? Or is that question incorrect?

Comment: Hi, @Ingvar, about your question "How can I include the interactive html to my latex pdf file? ", I think there is no way to do that.

Comment: @ollydbg23, hi, Okay, good to know.